# How to create game video while playing?

Tags: iphone, ipod

I am wondering how people are being able to record there game play?

Like this video is of [angry birds](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5Jk5JfKgv5U&feature=related) which shows game play.

please help as my game is near to the deployment so i can also create my game video and upload.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option would be to use [iSimulate](http://www.vimov.com/isimulate/) to send the simulator accelerometer data to the simulator and then to use screen recording software to capture video from the simulator.

Answer (score 1):

You could try playing the game in the simulator and recording your screen =p

Comment: thanks for your replay. but my app is used accelerometer so not play in simulator i play in ipod so please help me.